# Intersect of ImageView's in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Why these statements does not work?

```
if (iv_ship.intersects(iv_plane.getBoundsInLocal())) System.out.println("xxxxxxxxx");
if (iv_plane.intersects(iv_ship.getBoundsInLocal())) System.out.println("zzzz");
if (iv_plane.getBoundsInLocal().intersects(iv_ship.getBoundsInLocal())) System.out.println("dupa");
```

I am pretty sure these two objects intersect. Maybe it is fault of TranslateTransition?
But i was also trying to intersect Rectangles in coast, which are not TT.
Best regards.

Here is all the code:

```
package riverpuff.v3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Marek
 */
public class RiverPuffV3 extends Application {

    public String name = "";
    public Rectangle shot = new Rectangle();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        createMenu(primaryStage);

        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.getIcons().
                add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Icon.png")));
    }

    private void createMenu(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setScene(null);

        GridPane pane_menu = new GridPane();

        Button button_name = new Button("Name");
        button_name.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button_name.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button_name.setOnAction(e -> {
            createName(primaryStage);
            /*try{        
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream("log.txt", true), "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                fbw.newLine();
                fbw.write("append txt...");
                fbw.newLine();
                fbw.close();
            }
            catch (Exception v) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + v.getMessage());
            }*/
        });

        Button button_start = new Button("Start");
        button_start.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button_start.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button_start.setOnAction(e -> {
            drawGame(primaryStage);
        });

        pane_menu.setHgap(10);
        pane_menu.setVgap(10);
        pane_menu.add(button_name,0,10,10,10);
        pane_menu.add(button_start,15,10,10,10);

                                                                                //reading name from a file
        try {
            String read_file = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt"));
            read_file = in.readLine();
            Text text_name = new Text("Hello " + read_file);
            pane_menu.add(text_name,5,5,10,5);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            //throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error occured");
            //throw new RuntimeException("IO Error occured");
        } 

        Scene scene_menu = new Scene(pane_menu, 300, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("River Puff");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene_menu);

    }

                                                                                //save name to a file
    private void createName (Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setScene(null);

        GridPane pane_name = new GridPane();

        TextField tf_name = new TextField();
        tf_name.setMaxHeight(50);
        tf_name.setMaxWidth(240);
        tf_name.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tf_name.setFont(Font.font("Verdana",25));
        tf_name.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                name = tf_name.getText();
                if (!name.isEmpty()){
                    MyFile myFile = new MyFile();
                    myFile.writeTextFile("log.txt", name);
                }
                createMenu(primaryStage);
            }
        });
        Button button_ok = new Button("OK");        
        button_ok.setMaxHeight(30);
        button_ok.setMaxWidth(80);
        button_ok.setOnAction(e -> {
            name = tf_name.getText();
            if (!name.isEmpty()){
                MyFile myFile = new MyFile();
                myFile.writeTextFile("log.txt", name);
            }
            createMenu(primaryStage);
        });

        Text text_name = new Text("What is your name?");
        text_name.setFont(Font.font("Verdana",15));

        pane_name.setHgap(10);
        pane_name.setVgap(10);

        pane_name.add(text_name,8,9,5,5);
        pane_name.add(button_ok,11,22,8,3);
        pane_name.add(tf_name,3,15,24,5);

        Scene scene_name = new Scene(pane_name, 300, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("River Puff - Name");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene_name);

    }

    private void drawGame (Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setScene(null);

        final int H = 700;
        final int W = 1000;

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene_game = new Scene(root, W, H, Color.LIGHTBLUE);

        Button button_menu = new Button("Menu");
        button_menu.setOnAction(e ->{
            createMenu(primaryStage);
        });

        Image ship = new Image((getClass().getResourceAsStream("ship.png")));   //loading images
        Image plane = new Image((getClass().getResourceAsStream("Icon.png")));

        /**********************************************************************/

        Rectangle[] coastL = {
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle(),
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle(), 
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle(), 
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle()
        }; 
        Rectangle[] coastR = {            
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle(),
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle(), 
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle(), 
            new Rectangle(), new Rectangle()
        };


        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            coastL[i].setFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
            coastL[i].setHeight(100);
            coastR[i].setFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
            coastR[i].setHeight(100);
        }


        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            int[] j = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                for (int i=0; i<8; i++) if (j[i]==(i*100+800)) j[i]=i*100;

                for (int i=1;i<9;i++) {                                         //creating coast
                    coastL[i-1].setX(0);
                    coastL[i-1].setY(j[i-1]-(i*100));
                    coastL[i-1].setWidth(250+i*(i%3));

                    coastR[i-1].setX(W-(250+i*(i%4)));
                    coastR[i-1].setY(j[i-1]-(i*100));
                    coastR[i-1].setWidth(250+i*(i%4));
                } 
                for (int i=0;i<8;i++) j[i]++;
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        ImageView iv_ship = new ImageView();
        iv_ship.setImage(ship);
        iv_ship.setFitWidth(150);
        iv_ship.setFitHeight(45);
        iv_ship.setX(300);
        iv_ship.setY(0);

        TranslateTransition tt_shipX = 
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), iv_ship);        //moving enemies
        tt_shipX.setAutoReverse(true);
        tt_shipX.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);        
        tt_shipX.setByX(200f);
        tt_shipX.play();    

        TranslateTransition tt_shipY = 
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(13000), iv_ship);
        tt_shipY.setAutoReverse(false);
        tt_shipY.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        tt_shipY.setByY(800);
        tt_shipY.play();        

        ImageView iv_plane = new ImageView();
        iv_plane.setImage(plane);
        iv_plane.setFitWidth(50);
        iv_plane.setFitHeight(50);
        iv_plane.setX(475);
        iv_plane.setY(600);

        TranslateTransition tt_plane = 
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1), iv_plane);          

        TranslateTransition tt_shot = 
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(4000), shot);
        tt_shot.setAutoReverse(false);
        tt_shot.setCycleCount(1);
        TranslateTransition tt_shotB =
                new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(0.5f), shot);
        tt_shotB.setAutoReverse(false);
        tt_shotB.setCycleCount(1);

        root.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {                                 //steering a plane            }
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT && 
                    tt_plane.getNode().getTranslateX() > -475) {
                tt_plane.setByX(-5f);
                tt_plane.play();
                System.out.println(tt_plane.getNode().getTranslateX());
            }
            else if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT && 
                    tt_plane.getNode().getTranslateX() < 475) {
                tt_plane.setByX(5f);
                tt_plane.play();
                System.out.println(tt_plane.getNode().getTranslateX());
            }
            else if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                shot.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                shot.setX(tt_plane.getNode().getTranslateX()+495);
                shot.setY(580);
                shot.setWidth(10);
                shot.setHeight(20);

                tt_shot.setByY(-600);
                tt_shot.play();
                tt_shot.setOnFinished((ActionEvent arg0) -> {
                    shot.setDisable(true);
                    tt_shotB.setByY(600);
                    tt_shotB.play();
                });
            }
        });

        if (iv_ship.intersects(iv_plane.getBoundsInLocal())) System.out.println("xxxxxxxxx");
        if (iv_plane.intersects(iv_ship.getBoundsInLocal())) System.out.println("zzzz");
        if (iv_plane.getBoundsInLocal().intersects(iv_ship.getBoundsInLocal())) System.out.println("dupa");

        root.getChildren().add(button_menu);
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            root.getChildren().add(coastL[i]);
            root.getChildren().add(coastR[i]);
        }
        root.getChildren().add(iv_plane);
        root.getChildren().add(iv_ship);
        root.getChildren().add(shot);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene_game);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? What did you expect and what did you experience instead?

Comment: @LajosArpad, i expected to get something in my console while these two objects intersetct, but nothing happened in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to take into account that the nodes can be transformed (with translations), so instead of `getBoundsInLocal()` you need `getBoundsInParent()`.

According to javadocs:

> getBoundsInParent() gets the value of the property boundsInParent. The rectangular bounds of this Node which include its transforms. boundsInParent is calculated by taking the local bounds (defined by boundsInLocal) and applying the transform created.

This will work, at any given position of both nodes:

```
if(iv_plane.getBoundsInParent().intersects(iv_ship.getBoundsInParent())){
    System.out.println("Intersection detected");
}
```

The next problem you have to solve is when do you check a possible intersection. Based on your code, you checked only once, when the nodes where not even added to the root/scene/stage. That couldn't work.

For this to work, you have to check everytime one of them is moved, using some listeners to changes in the `translateXProperty()` and `translateYProperty()`, something like this:

```
private final ChangeListener<Number> checkIntersection = (ob,n,n1)->{
    if (iv_plane.getBoundsInParent().intersects(iv_ship.getBoundsInParent())){
        System.out.println("Intersection detected");
    }
};

private ImageView iv_ship, iv_plane;

private void drawGame (Stage primaryStage) {
    iv_ship = new ImageView();
    iv_plane = new ImageView();
    ...
    iv_ship.translateXProperty().addListener(checkIntersection);
    iv_ship.translateYProperty().addListener(checkIntersection);
    ...
    root.getChildren().addAll(iv_plane,iv_ship);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene_game);
}
```